# How to Move Column In Excel through VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

Say i h a work sheet in excel which is auto generated in Vb. 
The order of the Columns is user specified.
Say Normal Order is Ser No#   Order No    Customer Order No   Pcs    Qty   Price.

IF order is change say  Ser No#   Customer Order  Order No     No   Pcs    Qty   Price.

I h to write down whole code once again. Is there way to move excel column using vb code.

Comment: I suggest you utilize the changed order as a custom list; then your data horizontally based on that new list.

Comment: That should read "sort" your data horizontally based on that new list

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can order the column using vb code.

Check the below example where you can change the order for columns named as "Last Name" and "First Name" as you wish

```
   Dim oExcel As Object
   Dim oBook As Object
   Dim oSheet As Object

   'Start a new workbook in Excel
   Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add


   'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
   Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
   oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
   oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
   oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
   oSheet.Range("B2").Value = "John"

   'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
   oBook.SaveAs "C:\Book1.xls"
   oExcel.Quit
```